# Webclient handle errors when errors attribute is on body response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

The next code is used to call Google Recaptcha API.

Google Recaptcha APIs always return a 200 Ok code for every request, even when the secret is wrong.

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "error-codes": [
        "invalid-input-secret"
    ]
}
```

or

```json
{
   "success": true,
   "challenge_ts": "2023-09-13T19:04:58Z",
   "hostname": "qua.url.fr",
   "score": 0.9,
   "action": "getAccountWithCharacterCode"
}
```

How can I update the WebClient code so I can throw an exception without doing a .block() at the end of the call ?

```java
googleReCaptchaWebClient.post()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path("siteverify")
            .queryParam("secret", googleReCaptchaSecret)
            .queryParam("response", reCaptcha).build())
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(ReCaptchaResponse.class);
```

I tried to use `.exchangeToMono(clientResponse -> {});` but I did not find a way to avoid the block() method.

Comment: I have a similar case, I used a custom deserializer that would look inside the body and decides how to map the response. in case of an error, throw an exception and deal with it as per your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using retrieve(), you could use .exchangeToMono() instead while making sure to subscribe to your mono. This will give you the entire response and you can choose how to handle it.
For reference:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-webclient/client-exchange.html

You could try and use a jackson ObjectMapper and readValue method to convert the response to the class you'd like. If that conversion fails, you can then handle that error.

You could try just subscribing to the mono and then handling the response there.

```
googleReCaptchaWebClient
            .post()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path("siteverify")
            .queryParam("secret", googleReCaptchaSecret)
            .queryParam("response", reCaptcha).build())
            .exchangeToMono(response -> {
                try {
                    ReCaptchaResponse response = objectMapper.readValue(response.body(), ReCaptchaResponse.class);
                    // do more stuff
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // you know now that it's probably an error response
                    ErrorResponse response = objectMapper.readValue(response.body(), ErrorResponse.class);
                    // handle errors
                }

            });
```

Comment: I am using the last version of webflux and I don't have clientResponse.body()! The only acceptable signature is `<T> T body(BodyExtractor<T, ? super ClientHttpResponse> extractor)`